# Delay When Playing Sound using as3wavsound

Tags: actionscript-3, wav, audio

I am using the [as3wavsound](http://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/) class to play .wav sounds from file in my ActionScript 3 project. However, even though I am preloading the sounds, I am getting a delay of about 1 second every time I play one. The delay is the same, regardless of .wav length or bitrate.

How do I fix this delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the buffer size in [as3wavsound](http://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/). To fix it...

1) Open WavSoundPlayer.as

2) Replace the following code:

```
public static var MAX_BUFFERSIZE:Number = 8192;
```

with...

```
public static var MAX_BUFFERSIZE:Number = 2048;// 8192;
```

Save and close WavSoundPlayer.as, and then run your project again. This should fix the delay.

---

**(Answer credit goes to [morskoyz](http://code.google.com/u/117516888526039724360/))**

**([Original question and answer on the as3wavsound bug report.](http://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=17))**