# ActionScript : Sound from ByteArray has lag

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, arrays, microphone, lag

In my application, I use the microphone to record and get the result in `ByteArray`, then, I convert it in playable `Sound` by using the `WavSound` class from `org.as3wavsound`.

Record and play work correctly except a huge lag at the launching of the sound *( Easily 2 secondes )*.

My code is something like this :

```
import org.as3wavsound.WavSound;
import org.bytearray.micrecorder.encoder.WaveEncoder;
import org.bytearray.micrecorder.MicRecorder;

/* ... */

var wavEncoder:WaveEncoder = new WaveEncoder( 0.5 );
var recorder:MicRecorder = new MicRecorder( wavEncoder );
recorder.record();

/* ... */

recorder.stop();
var sound:WavSound = new WavSound( recorder.output );

/* ... */

sound.play();
```

Thanks a lot to help me understand what's wrong in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue with the `as3wavsound` library: [Delay When Playing Sound using as3wavsound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556083/delay-when-playing-sound-using-as3wavsound/13556084#13556084)

The answer on that post tells you to decrease the `MAX_BUFFERSIZE` in `WavSoundPlayer` to 2048.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't see the previous answers. That's work perfectly.